# Prolog more than one argument or a list as a comparison for a query?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and struggling with queries.
So I want to allow the user to input any number of arguments for my query.
right now I can only get it to work for one argument

```
aminofor(X) :-
   aminoname(X,_,Z),
   aminoclass(Z,'Hydropathy',A),
   print('Hydropathy'),
   print(A).
```

with that if I enter a valid input for `X`, it'll output 'Hydropathy' and then the value of `A`.

However, I want to make it so that I could enter multiple inputs for `X` and then have it will give me the `hydropathy`.

e.g. right now if I enter `aminofor(g)`. it will tell  me `Hydropathy` neutral however if I enter `aminofor(g,h)`. it will say

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: aminofor/2
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         aminofor/1
false.
```

How do I solve this, apologies in advance for the problem explanation however any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want 'Hydropathy' to be passed as an argument?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] and let us know what Prolog environment you're running this under? It's 1000% easier if we can run your code.

Comment: Of course it will show an error if you pass two arguments to a predicate that accepts only one. If you want to pass multiple arguments, if it's a fixed number, then define your predicate with that number of arguments. If it's a variable number of arguments, you could consider using a list.

Comment: Yes I'd like to pass multiple arguments that fit, however I'm not sure how to do that, after some research im looking at using the append statement